# what do javascript "function || function || function" mean ??

Tags: javascript

`avoidP2P() || t < lowBuffer || 0 === a.size(p2pManager.swarm.utils.contributors) ? requestToCDN() : requestToP2P()`

If the above functions are as follows: A || B || C

Does C run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JavaScript, the `||` operator means "or". So for a function like `A || B || C`:

**1.** JavaScript will first try to evaluate the value of `A`, if it is `true`, the execution will stop and `B` and `C` won't even get called.

**2.** However, if `A` evaluates `falsy`, then JS will execute  `B`. In the same manner, if  `B` returns `true`, then execution is stopped and `C` won't get called.

**3.** Only and only if both `A` and `B` evaluates `false`, then JS will try `C` hoping to get a `true` value.

For your reference, falsy values are:

```
null
false
0
undefined
''
[]
{}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: @sujkh85 No problem. If my answer helps you, please accept the answer by clicking the green checked button on the left. Happy coding!

Comment: To be precise, `A` is not "run" and does not "return" anything. It is "evaluated" to some "value". Also, for clarity, it's probably better to use "falsy" instead of "false". `false` has a very specific meaning as a boolean value.

Comment: @torazaburo You have a point, I'll try to fix the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It means "Get the first value from these that is not falsy", being "falsy" some of:

```
false
null
undefined
0
NaN
''
```

More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy